# What happens when stripe billing cycle anchor is on 31st or leap year?

Tags: stripe-payments

We are setting up stripe to manage monthly billing subscriptions for our site. As per 
[Stripe Documents](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle)
we will be using 'billing cycle anchor' to default to the date when the user subscribed to the service. From the document it states the client will be billed monthly on this date. Eg plan starting on the 15th, will always be billed on the 15th.

The question I have what happens if the monthly plan started on 31st or leap year ie Feb 29th?

How does stripe manage the monthly payment in this instance? ie what date monthly anchor date does it default too?

I am unable to find any information in stripe but if someone let me know the protocol and where stripe has documented it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 8):

If a plan starts/is anchored on the 31st, it will then bill on the last day of the month each month. If a plan starts on leap day, it will bill on the 29th of each the month going forward, and then the 28th next February.

From https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle

> If a month does not have the anchor day, the subscription will be billed on the last day of the month. For example, a subscription starting on January 31 bills on February 28 (or February 29 in a leap year), then March 31, April 30, and so on.

Comment: This stripe document is very vague. It also says "The billing cycle anchor defaults to when the subscription was created". Therefore the 'anchor day' DOES exists. The doc doesn't say  that an anchor date doesn't exist if the subscription was on or after the 28th. To think so with out documentation would be presumptuous. It's bad for a coder to presume. If I post on a website that a member's work will be purged by a given anchor date and get that day wrong, someone gonna be pissed at me when the customer calls complaining.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, "a month does not have the anchor day" means that the anchor day is set to eg. 31st, and some other month for which we want to calculate the billing is 28, 29 or 30 days long. The anchor date as such does exist.

Comment: I used Stripe's TestClock to verify this, but found that the renewal dates are not always the last days of the month. For example, if I start a monthly subscription on 2023-01-31, the next invoices will be issued on: 2023-03-01, 2023-03-31, 2023-05-01, and 2023-05-31. The differences are anything between 29 and 31 days and I couldn't see a logic behind it.

Comment: billing_cycle_anchor_config seems to be a bit easier to use than billing_cycle_anchor.  (just say 31 and it does the right thing) However afaict you can't use it for stripe checkout which stinks.